# add dynamic marker to maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Im trying to create a dynamic marker in google maps but the map doesen't load, the maps activity does load but it doesen't create de marker.
here is the code:

```
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;





public class Mapa extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
public double posx;
public double posy;
public String desc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //SupportMapFragment googleMap=(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    posx= b.getDouble("PosicionX");
    posy= b.getDouble("PosicionY");
    desc = b.getString("Descripcion");


}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng lugar = new LatLng(posx, posy);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lugar).title(desc));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lugar));
}
}
```

Im using a bundle to receive the information send from the previous activty, which sends two doubles and one string. for some reason it opens the maps_activity when i run it on my phone but it doesen't create the marker. 
I wont paste the whole xml code, but the map object is named "map"

Comment: Maybe you have exchanged latitude and longitude... have you tried doing `LatLng lugar = new LatLng(posy, posx);`?

Comment: Try to name your extras latitude and longitude so you do not confuse the ordering

Comment: Also `LatLng` implements `Parcelable` so it can be directly added to a `Bundle` via `putParcelable` and retrieved using `getParcelable`

Comment: The problem is not that i get the reversed location (latitude and longitude aren't getting mixed) the problem is that this doesn't create the marker on the map

Comment: Does the camera get moved to the correct location?

Comment: it does absolutely nothing, it opens a grey screen with google's logo on the bottom-left of the screen and thats it, it doesen't even load the map

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code is just fine, the problem was the version of Android i was developing for, since it was an older version of the one i have on my phone, for some reason it just wouldn't open google maps correctly, therefore i had to remake the hole app to the same android version i have on my phone.